# How do I replace the values in one file with the values in another file?

Tags: python, bash

I have 2 tab-separated files which look like this:

**file1.txt**

```
chr1    710000  715000  143
chr1    715000  720000  144
chr1    720000  725000  145
chr1    725000  730000  146
chr1    730000  735000  147
chr1    735000  740000  148
chr1    740000  745000  149
chr1    745000  750000  150
chr1    750000  755000  151
chr1    755000  760000  152
chr1    760000  765000  153
```

**file2.txt**

```
143 143 84
143 144 26
143 152 32
143 153 15
144 152 11
```

The expected output:

**output.txt**

```
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    710000  715000  84
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    715000  720000  26
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    755000  760000  32
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    760000  765000  15
chr1    715000  720000  chr1    755000  760000  11
```

I would like to match the unique numbers in **file1.txt** (column 4) with the numbers in **file2.txt** (column 1 and 2) and replace them with values from **file1.txt** (column 1-3). The **output.txt** should have 7 columns, where the last one have the corresponding values from the **file2.txt** (column 3).

Comment: Are the files sorted/sortable? Getting them into matching order will likely simplify the needed logic. Also, how big are the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If file1.txt isn't extremely large you can load it into memory and use table lookups.

```
$: cat match
#! /bin/env bash

declare -a lookup=()
while read a b c i
do lookup[$i]="$a       $b      $c" # embedded tabs here
done < file1.txt

while read a b v
do printf "%s\t%s\t$v\n" "${lookup[$a]}" "${lookup[$b]}" # use quotes!
done < file2.txt

$: bash match
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    710000  715000  84
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    715000  720000  26
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    755000  760000  32
chr1    710000  715000  chr1    760000  765000  15
chr1    715000  720000  chr1    755000  760000  11
```

Comment: If the first file is too big you might need to do sorted parallel reads, which is doable but more work.

Comment: Also, this might be more efficient with an associative array if there are going to be a lot of unused cells. Anyone have thoughts on that?

Comment: As you suspected the files are huge, thank you for your help and advice. It seems like it is working, although really slowly.
For those of you how are interested, the above files are outputs of HiC-Pro pipeline that generates intra- and inter-chromosomal contact maps.

Comment: Might be faster to reimplement in Perl with the same logic. Do we need to write the faster and/or less memory abusive version?

Comment: If you're really memory-bound, then it might actually speed it up to only add records to the lookup when they are needed, and then remove them from the table when you're sure you will no longer need them. It's more work to keep checking and then doing add/delete actions to support a moving window, but with a really big dataset could free up a *huge* amount of memory for performance.

Comment: Honestly, the better way for a really big dataset would be to use a database optimized for this sort of thing. I don't suppose you have a mysql instance lying around and could do this in SQL? XD

Comment: Paul, thank you very much for help. Your script at the end worked really well.

Comment: Great to hear! Accept the solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

The [`q` command](http://harelba.github.io/q/index.html) can apply sql queries to tabular text files. The following command produces your expected output.

```
q -t 'SELECT a.c1, a.c2, a.c3, b.c1, b.c2, b.c3, c.c3
      FROM ./file2.txt c
      JOIN ./file1.txt a ON a.c4 = c.c1
      JOIN ./file1.txt b ON b.c4 = c.c2'
```

It's pretty neat but not very fast for large files. However, it could be way faster than a plain bash solution.

On Ubuntu you can install `q` with `apt install python-q-text-as-data`.